# Generate a new random number using scheduled executor and then passing that number as a new time interval in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Good morning,

I want to start a scheduled thread that generates a new random number every time it executes and then uses that new number as the interval before it fires again.  I have previously used the roughly following code to execute a thread running on a regularly scheduled interval:

```
public void start() {

    long delay = 5;

    final Runnable g = () -> {
            delay = (long)(50 * (Math.random()+0.1));
            thingDoer.doAwesomeThings();
    };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> passerbyGenerator = schedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(g, 1, delay, 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I have never attempted to do this without a fixed interval.  I know what I have above will not work.
Firstly, the last line of code sets the schedule and is only executed once.  Secondly, it looks like I cannot use a changing variable inside of a scheduled thread. I get following error: "local variable delay defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final."

How can I start a thread that does what I want to do?  Put another way, how can I schedule a beeper that beeps at irregular intervals?

Comment: I would start thread with endless loop and use Thread.sleep(randomMilis) after every beep.

Comment: What is the point of `+0.1` part?

Comment: Perhaps I am incorrect but Math.random() generates a between 0.0--0.9 doesn't it?  I don't want the generated number to be zero.  If I am wrong I am happy to be corrected.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you don't want to random to be a zero, you can add some constant to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ThingDoer implements Runnable {

    private long delay;

    public ThingDoer(int initialDelay) {
        this.delay = initialDelay;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new ThingDoer(5)).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                delay = (long) ((Math.random() + 0.1) * 50);

                doAwesomeThings();
                System.out.println(String.format("next delay: %s", delay));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void doAwesomeThings() {
        System.out.println("did something awesome");
    }

}
```

Actual Output:

```
did something awesome
next delay: 31
did something awesome
next delay: 12
did something awesome
next delay: 48
did something awesome
next delay: 31
did something awesome
next delay: 44
did something awesome
next delay: 20
did something awesome
next delay: 26
did something awesome
next delay: 18
did something awesome
next delay: 39
did something awesome
next delay: 32
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Brickowski.  I was overly complicating the issue.